# Delete all emails containing a certain string in the body of the message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell

In Outlook, is it possible to automate the deletion of all emails containing a certain string in the body? I see that this can be done for a string in the subject, but I don't see how to do it for a string in the body of the message.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with "powershell"? You want to automate the deletion using the powershell?

Comment: I have no preference in how it is accomplished. I thought that that might be one way it could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with Outlook 2013's Advanced Rules wizard. See below:

[image: Create Rule]

[image: Outlook 2013 Advanced Rules Wizard]